# Css styles not applying to page

Tags: html, css

I have page called NEW with a from on it, at the top of it I am including an external page which includes my styles. I am linking to the styles on this page the same way that I did on another page but for some reason on this page the style is not applying even though I am using the exact same route on a different page. What could be going on here?

Page where the styles are working properly:

```
<% layout('partials/layout') -%>

  <h1 class="heading">Pet Gallery!</h1>     

  <div class="blog-home2 spacer">
  <div class="container gallery-container">
              <div class="row m-t-40">
             <% posts.forEach(function(post) { %> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-duration="1200">
                      <!-- spot where image should go -->
                    <h1><%=post.name %></h1>
                    <span><%=post.fee %></span>
                    <span><%=post.description %></span>
                    <span><%= post.location%></span>  
                    <div><a href="/gallery/pet/<%=post.id %>">View More</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <% }) %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Page where the styles aren't applying:

```
<% layout('partials/layout') -%>

<h1>New Pet</h1>

<form action="/gallery" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div>
    <input type="text" name="post[name]" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="post[fee]" placeholder="Rehoming Fee">
</div>
<div>
    <textarea name="post[description]"  placeholder="Description"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="post[location]"placeholder="Location">
</div>
    <input type="file" accept='images/*' name="images"  multiple>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit">
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjj7C.png
```

Code containing navbar and style link :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= title %>></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/post-show.css">

</head>
<body>
    <% include ../partials/navbar %>
    <% include ../partials/flash-message %>
    <%-body -%>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The structures of the two pages seem dramatically different. Which styles are not being applied? It might help to include the relevant CSS to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: the navbar is colored and styled on the top example but those styles aren't coming through on bottom example. Strangely, the bootstrap styles are coming in on the second example but the navbar styles are not. So somehow it's getting the bootstrap styles same as the example above but it's not getting the navbar styles the same.

Comment: getting any console error?

Comment: no console errors

Answer (score 0):

`<% layout('/partials/layout') -%>` has a leading forward slash. This means the browser will start searching at the top level of the domain. So if your current directory is `http://example.com/pages/`:

`/partials/layout` will search in `http://example.com/partials/layout`

while

`partials/layout` will search in `http://example.com/pages/partials/layout`

Comment: Sorry let me post the updated fix....still isn't working even with the slash being fixed.

Comment: @TNT928 what is your directory structure like? Where are all these files?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was finally able to figure out the problem. I was missing a forward slash on the on the link to the stlyesheet. Still not sure what that worked for one page but not the other but alas, the problem is solved. Thanks for the help.